# How come this code in python is valid? There is no if matching the else

Tags: if-statement

There is no if statement matching one of the else: statement. Does having a try-except within an if block affect the indentation?

```
if 0 != sys.argv[1].find("clean"): #Dont check if we are cleaning!
if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
    try:
        files = O.listdir(O.path.join(libdirs))
        print "files is ",files
    except:
        raise Exception("The FMI Library binary cannot be found at path: "+str(O.path.join(libdirs)))
    for file in files:
        if "fmilib_shared" in file and not file.endswith("a"):
            print "was true for ", file
            shutil.copy2(O.path.join(libdirs,file),O.path.join(".","src","pyfmi"))
            fmilib_shared = O.path.join(".","src","pyfmi",file)
            print "fmilib_shared is ",fmilib_shared
            break
    else: # THIS IS THE ELSE BLOCK IN QUESTION
        print "We have entered the else block in question"
        raise Exception("Could not find FMILibrary at: %s"%libdirs)
    print "copy_gcc_lib flying sheep ", copy_gcc_lib    
    if copy_gcc_lib:
        path_gcc_lib = ctypes.util.find_library("libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll")
        if path_gcc_lib != None:
            shutil.copy2(path_gcc_lib,O.path.join(".","src","pyfmi"))
            gcc_lib = O.path.join(".","src","pyfmi","libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll")
```

The code is from the setup.py file of the PyFMI library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `else` statement is connected to the `for` loop, not the `except` block. Using an `else` clause on a `for` loop is perfectly fine and it will be executed if the loop exhaust the list it is iterating over. For more documentation, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

What happens in the code is that if `files = ...` causes an exception, it will be caught and an informative message will be printed together with a new exception (in this case the `for` loop will never be executed). If there is No exception, the `for` loop will iterate over the files searching for one specifically. If this file is not found, the `else` clause on the `for` loop will be executed and an exception raised. However, if the file is found, the `break` statement will cause the `for` loop to terminate prematurely and thus the `else` clause will not be executed.

To answer your question, a try-except block does not affect the indentation.